# What is the most efficient way of loading scripts for Social Network APIs?

Tags: javascript, html, social-networking, external-script, embedded-script

Like most websites these days, my personal website has an array of widgets for social networks, such as “Like”, “Follow” and “Share” buttons etc.

In order to embed these widgets, I use the JavaScript code that is provided on the social networks’ developer sites, plus the HTML5 markup with the relevant `data-*` attributes for “hooks” for the buttons.

At present, these API “loader” functions are located in an external `.js` file which is triggered via a `<SCRIPT>` element located in the `<HEAD>` of the web page.

I notice that these “loader” functions call another file from the relevant social networks’ server. Using Facebook’s JavaScript loader function as an example:

```js
(function(d,s,id) {
  var js,fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
}
(document,'script','facebook-jssdk'));
```

This function calls the Facebook's main API script:

[connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js](https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js)

I also have the Twitter and Google+ loader functions in the same external file.

However, although I am far from an expert in JavaScript and how it relates to caching, but I get the feeling that using an external script is such causing cache-related problems. These buttons seem to have a mind of their own, and whether they actually load or not seems to be a matter of pot-luck! I was wondering if it is anything to do with my Apache server automatically sending out a `Last-Modified:` HTTP header.

In short, the question that I want answered is this:

**Which is the most *efficient* and *bug-free* method of triggering these API loaders: via an external or embedded script?**

In other words: do you think that embedding the API loader functions will improve the buttons’ loading and performance – or does it rally matter whether the code is **embedded** or in an **external file**?